# Javascript remaping array into object the 0 (zero) values are excluded

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a (another) problem: Remaping an array into object the 0 (zero) values are excluded. Why and how to make to not ignore this value? I need this 0 (zero) value. :)

My array:

```
var data = {
"queryInfo": {
    "totalRows": "18"
},
    "resultset": [
    ["A", "MAXI", "ACC - GC", "SER", 5646.5],
    ["A", "MAXI", "ACC - SACC", "KIT", 2474.93],
    ["A", "MAXI", "ACC - SACC", "NET", 5418.72],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "ACC - DIV", "FORM", 1531.04],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "ACC - DIV", "FOR", 1147.5],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "ACC - DIV", "HI TECH", 0],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "ACC - GC", "TEM", 435],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "ACC - LPI", "ALYS", 651],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "ACC - LPI", "FIR", 0],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "SCC", "DRUM", 3693.36],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "SCC", "HEL", 0],
    ["A+", "MAXI", "SCC", "LOT", 873],
    ["B", "MAXI", "SCC", "PUR", 9356],
    ["B", "MAXI", "SCC", "SQU", 48474.06],
    ["B", "MAXI", "#null", "HA", 1711],
    ["B", "MAXI", "#null", "#null", 1197.6],
    ["#null", "MAXI", "#null", "#null", 2940],
    ["#null", "#null", "#null", "#null", 2372]
],
    "metadata": [{
    "colIndex": 0,
        "colType": "String",
        "colName": "CP"
}, {
    "colIndex": 1,
        "colType": "String",
        "colName": "ST"
}, {
    "colIndex": 2,
        "colType": "String",
        "colName": "GR"
}, {
    "colIndex": 3,
        "colType": "String",
        "colName": "PR"
}, {
    "colIndex": 4,
        "colType": "Numeric",
        "colName": "VALUE"
}]
};
```

and my function:

```
function recom(resultset) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < resultset.length; j++) {
    if (resultset[j]) {
        obj[data.metadata[j].colName] = resultset[j];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.resultset.length; i++) {
  if (data.resultset[i] !== null) {
    arr.push(recom(data.resultset[i]));
  }
}
```

This function take every metadata and is added as key in next final array.
As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxg1974/g48jr/) the result must be in this form:
**{"CP":"A+","ST":"MAXI","GR":"SCC","PR":"DRUM","VALUE":3693.36}**, but when index 4 of data.resultset is 0 (zero) my function return nothing at that level:
**{"CP":"A+","ST":"MAXI","GR":"SCC","PR":"HEL"}**

correct result is:
**{"CP":"A+","ST":"MAXI","GR":"SCC","PR":"HEL","VALUE":0}**

The index "VALUE" is missing due 0 value from resultsel.
How to make my function to work correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: `if (resultset[j])`: hint in Javascript `0` is falsy

Comment: thank you very much! my bad. Now it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition in `recom` to explicitly check for zero:

So instead of this:

```
if (resultset[j])
```

Try this:

```
if (resultset[j] === 0 || resultset[j])
```